# Rails uniq pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a the unique elements from a relation but they are distinguished by pairs of IDs. The following example illustrates what I want to do:

```
array.uniq {|post| post.a_id && post.b_id }
```

Unfortunately, the above will only return me the elements which have both a unique a_id and b_id. That is not want I want. I would like it to return me the unique pairs of those. Therefore, if I had the following posts with a_id and b_id respectively (shown below), I want it to return only post1, post3 and post4.

```
post1 1 2
post2 1 2
post3 1 3
post4 2 3
```

Thanks in advance for all of the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
array.uniq {|post| [ post.a_id, post.b_id ] }
```